# Autostart multiple apache2 instances on start up

Tags: linux, mysql, boot, apache-http-server

I have an OpenSUSE 13.1 installation, on which I am running multiple instances of apache under a proxy instance of apache. Currently I can start the proxy instance of apache and its MySQL database on startup by using the following commands:

```
chkconfig mysql on
chkconfig apache2 on
```

However, my sub-apache instances are currently started manually by me with the following command:

```
apache2ctl start -f /etc/apache2/instances/v01/httpd.conf
# Where v01 changes from v01->v0x, where x can be between 1 and 9
```

Does anyone know how I can get this command to run on start up? I have tried putting a script inside `/init.d/rc3.d/S10servers` to no avail, as well as modifying the `after.local`, `before.local` and `boot.local`.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

NOTE: If anyone knows how to also start multiple MySQL instances on a start up with seperate ports and data locations, that would be greatly appreciated (Still haven't looked into this, just thought I'd stick it on the end here).

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom startup services using `/etc/init.d/skeleton` as base. You can run `insserv my-service-name` to install this service.

`after.local` is not enabled by default, you can do it through `systemctl enable after-local.service`.

You can get more info on https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43230/how-to-run-my-script-after-suse-finished-booting-up